# POI is reading xlsx file blank second time in weblogic web application

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, weblogic

I have a standalone jar which I use to read (by POI) an xlsx file and load data into tables. This code is in Spring 3.2 and works perfect as a java program.
I want to use this jar in a web application wherein user would upload file to server at temp location first, then web application would call method of this jar to validate and load data into tables. First time is OK. File gets uploaded, POI reads data. But second time POI does not read the excel sheet data. It reads blanks even though sheet has data. When I restart weblogic 12C server, first time everything goes good. Again problem starts.
Please suggest me what the issue could be. I use POI-3.11, Java 1.6, Spring 3.2.

Comment: please post some code to help others to spot the issue.

Comment: maybe the temp location is deleting the file, you may check that first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the issue resolved. Columns are mentioned in property file. Spring loads object and injects these property values in the static ArrayList instance variables. After first xlsx upload, again this object is instantiated which adds to static ArrayList. This is causing POI read wrong columns which are blanks. I have removed static keyword from all variables and getting correct results.